# How to extract java version using DOS command

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, cmd.exe

I am trying to extract the version of java in my system using the

```
java -fullversion
```

which is providing an output

```
openjdk full version "1.x.y.124357"
```

I need to store this java version **1.x.y.124357** in a variable without quotes.

Please suggest any approach for this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('java -fullversion 2^>^&1 1^>nul') do set version="%a"
set version=%version:"=%
echo %version%
```

If it's in a batch file, you have to write `%%a` instead of `%a`, see [this](https://www.programming-books.io/essential/batch/for-bad676c158e747ff96145309fead1b63).

To get only the last part of the string:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('java -fullversion 2^>^&1 1^>nul') do for /f "tokens=4" %t in ("%a") do set version=%~t
echo %version%
```

If the version string is not necessarily the 4th token, but it's always the last one, you can do:

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('java -fullversion 2^>^&1 1^>nul') do for %t in (%a) do set version=%~t
echo %version%
```

See also:

- [Set output of a command as a variable (with pipes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952295/set-output-of-a-command-as-a-variable-with-pipes)
- [How to redirect error stream to variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29740883/how-to-redirect-error-stream-to-variable)
- [Last token in batch variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473840/last-token-in-batch-variable)

Comment: Hi Jean, This command is generating the full output. I only need the version number like 1.x.y.124357

Comment: @SwastikBanerjee Updated

Comment: Use the ~ modifier to strip off the quotes `for /f "tokens=4" %A in ('java -fullversion 2^>^&1') do @set "Version=%~A"` or `for /f "delims=" %A in ('java -fullversion 2^>^&1') do @for %B in (%A) do @set "Version=%~B"`

Comment: @LotPings That's right, the additional `set version=%version:"=%` is then eliminated. Corrected, thanks.